# "The information were successful updated." or "The information were updated successfully."

Tags: sentence-construction

Which one is more correct?

> The information were successful  updated.

or

> The information were updated successfully.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Neither.

> The information was updated successfully.

or

> The information was successfully updated.

Are both correct though with minimal amounts of difference in meaning. The only real difference is whether you are putting the stress on the update or the success.

Answer (score 1):

"The information" is singular.

Both

> The information was successfully updated.

and

> The information was updated successfully.

are correct.

The word "**successfully**" is modifying the verb "**was updated**". It therefore is an adverb, and must end with "*-ly*".  (The word "**successful**" is an adjective, and is only used to modify nouns).

Comment: +1. He could also say "The information update was successful". This is the case of using the adjective **successful** to modify the noun **update**.